# Automatic application of suggestions in Java language tool

Tags: java, languagetool

I want to output an already corrected text instead of the format below.

```
JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new BritishEnglish());
List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check("A sentence with a error in the Hitchhiker's Guide tot he Galaxy");
for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
  System.out.println("Potential error at characters " +
      match.getFromPos() + "-" + match.getToPos() + ": " +
      match.getMessage());
  System.out.println("Suggested correction(s): " +
      match.getSuggestedReplacements());
}
```

so the output should be like "A sentence with An error......"

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem when I needed to create a "Did you mean" for the search engine that I'm developing.  The following code seemed to do the trick:

```
public String didYouMean(String query) {

    JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new BritishEnglish());
    List<RuleMatch> matches = null;
    try {
        matches = langTool.check(query);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String didYouMean = "";
    int lastPos = 0;

    for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
        didYouMean += query.substring(lastPos, match.getFromPos());
        didYouMean += match.getSuggestedReplacements().get(0);
        lastPos = match.getToPos();       
    }

    if (lastPos < query.length()) {
        didYouMean += query.substring(lastPos, query.length());
    }

    return didYouMean;
}
```

By iterating over the matches, I was able to append the original query string (i.e. the string with the errors) to a new String, but replacing the errors with the first suggested replacement from LanguageTool.

Hope this helps!